# Why isn't my Submit button with ng-disabled attribute is enabled when date input field is invalidated using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, validation, form-submit

I'm using my client side form validation  using AngularJS. I intentionally type date input field as 'hhhh', which should get invalidated date field and submit button is disabled. While it is not as expected. Here is my cde snippet.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="dob" id="date"  name="dob" ng-model="dob" placeholder="type your valid Date of Birth: YYYY-MM-DD" ng-pattern="^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" class="form-control" required></input>
    <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$untouched" class="help-block">Date Of Birth is required</p>
    <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$touched && myForm.dob.$invalid" class="help-block">Please enter valid Date of Birth</p>
    <button type="submit" action="/register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
var MultilingualApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
MultilingualApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
});
```

I'd request you to please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the form tag, and the input type has to be `date` not dob

```
<form name="myForm">
        <input type="date" id="date"  name="dob" ng-model="dob" placeholder="type your valid Date of Birth: YYYY-MM-DD" ng-pattern="^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" class="form-control" required></input>
        <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$untouched" class="help-block">Date Of Birth is required</p>
        <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$touched && myForm.dob.$invalid" class="help-block">Please enter valid Date of Birth</p>
        <button type="submit" action="/register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Ohh I overlooked the type attribute of date input field. Nyways, Thank you so much for your kind response.  Got solved!